# How to easily save some models from Django as SQLite?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-orm

I need in my project (based on Postgresql) to export few models as SQLite dump. It must be made 'on-demand' f.e. on user request.

I can prepare appropriate database manually, but I would like to omit the duplication of information about schema. I dream about solution like 'dumpdata app-name' but instead of JSON/XML/YAML there should be SQLite.

Is there such solution?

P.S. For too overbearing - it's not broad question. Possibilities are only two: there is such snippet, helper etc. or there is not and it should be done individually. I can't find it by my own so I ask for help.

To sum up details (some people could not figure them out and could put my question 'on hold'):

- there is Django project with main Postgresql database
- I'm already processing request from users (through an API)
- one of request is "make a dump of some models (tables) in SQLite format"
- I can prepare temporary SQLite database and **manually** fill it with data
- I'm looking for powerful and universal tool (solution) which will do such export automatically (from some of my Django models to SQLite)

Comment: If you're asking for a tool, then its either a tool recommendation question or a 'gimme teh code' question, both of which are off topic on S.O. My suggestion would be to convert the json from dumpdata to a database.

Comment: First of all thank you for discussion and not putting my problem 'on hold'. 

Your suggestion doesn't fully solve the problem. I can of course call dumpdata (in code for processing user request) using django.core.management.call_command and I can get JSON for models from specific applications. But I need a way to convert it to SQLite which is needed as a response on user request. If I do it by converting from JSON I lose informations about types of fieds. So it's imperfect solution.

Comment: I can also do something 'manually' reading field types in model._meta.fields and creating proper columns in my temporary SQLite database then filling it by iterate models from applications. But it will be enough for simplest models. When things get complicated (foreign keys etc.) I could not prepare such code by my own.

That's why I'm looking for sophisticated tool or 'gimme teh code' solution.

Comment: ... and of course I don't understand why my question is "off topic on S.O". I have specific problem. I can't find appropriate solution (save temporarily only 'some' data as SQLite when main database should be independent). Where should I ask and discuss it? All mine ideas are not good enough. Yours is also imperfect. Maybe someone will know f.e. some converter which will be helpfull or maybe someone solve it already in much better way I or yoy can develop. Still off topic? We're not talking about beer or cars ...

Comment: You don't have a specific problem. "Exporting data to a SQLite database" is a broad task with many solutions (one of which I suggested). Doing so generally would require loading Django's models, generating a SQLite schema for them, and copying the data over, which isn't an easy task. _"Maybe someone will know f.e. some converter"_ is a blatant tool recommendation question which is [explicitly off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I still disagree. Suggested by you solution is inappropriate and simply does not even apply to this problem. I suppose your point of view is too narrow and you should broaden your horizons. Let me one more time explain to you the crux.

If I would ask how to easilly export data from Django main database to JSON, you would have said 'use dumpdata' as easiest and best way, despite there are dozens other possibilities. 

But in my situation I need to export only some of models and not to JSON, but to SQLite, preserving models schema in exported database.By the way it must be made as one of views.

Comment: Do you stil insist that there are many solutions? Then please give me in general only five meaningful if it its so broad task.